# "Should probably not check" vs. "probably should not check."

Tags: phrase-choice

Do they mean the same? Is one more correct/natural than the other?

Example sentence:

> Did he have missed calls from Mary? He **should probably not
> check/probably shouldn't check**.

I tried searching trends in Google Ngrams, but I couldn't get [any](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=should%20probably%20not%20check%2C%20probably%20should%20not%20check%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=) results.

Comment: You got no results because you used too many words. [The search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=should+probably+not%2Cprobably+should+not&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshould%20probably%20not%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprobably%20should%20not%3B%2Cc0) works better if you leave out "check."

Comment: He probably shouldn't go out tonight. versus He should probably not go out tonight. mean the same exact thing.  Both are grammatical. But the contraction would probably not be written in a formal document.

Comment: The nGram viewer conflates "should not" with "shouldn't". "*Probably shouldn't*" is the most natural. "*Probably should not*" is less natural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are fine. "probably shouldn't" is more frequent.